# Using Web API JSON Response from AngularJS - Error: expected and array but got an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API which is returning a response in JSON, in this format:

```
{
  "email": "john@google.com",
  "password": null,
  "accessLevel": 2
}
```

I am trying to access the accessLevel field within that response, but I am getting this Angular error:

```
Error in resource configuration for action `query`. Expected response to contain an array but got an object (Request: GET http://localhost:51608/api/UserRole?email=john@google.com...)
```

This is my Angular resource code (below), I just added the isArray false to attempt to solve the issue:

```
function userRoleResource($resource, appSettings) {
    return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/UserRole?email=:email", { email: '@email' },
    {
        get: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: false
        }
    });
}
```

And this is how I am attempting to use the data:

```
userRoleResource.query({ email: vm.userData.email },
   function (data) {
      vm.userData.accessLevel = data.AccessLevel;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're specifying that the 'get' function is not an array, but you're using the 'query' function.

try this:

```
userRoleResource.get({ email: vm.userData.email },
    function (data) {
        vm.userData.accessLevel = data.AccessLevel;
});
```